# Python - Terminate Child Process or PID?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a script (simplified below) that initiates another python process.  I know the process name and PID for the current and child processes.

When I attempt to terminate the child process - menu option (2) - I get the message "local variable 'py_process' referenced before assignment."

Suggestions to terminate this process?  Is this a variable scoping issue?

EDIT:  Defined 'py_process' as a Global var inside exec_menu(). :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
import subprocess

## Path Variables ##
pyTivoPath="c:\pyTivo\pyTivo.py"

def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

## Main Menu ##
def main_menu():
    print "\nmyPID: %d\n" % (os.getpid())
    print "1. Start pyTivo"
    print "2. Stop pyTivo"
    choice=raw_input ("\nSelect: ")
    exec_menu(choice)
    return

## Menu Action ##
def exec_menu(choice):
    gobal py_process
    if choice=="1":
        print "\nStarting pyTivo..."
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
        py_process = subprocess.Popen(pyTivoPath, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        newPID=py_process.pid
        print "newPID: %d" % (newPID)
    elif choice=="2":
        print "stopping pyTivo"
        py_process.terminate()
    else:
        exit()
    return

## Main Loop ## 
main_menu()

raw_input("\nPress Enter to continue...")
main_menu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a variable scoping issue.

`py_process` doesn't exist on your subsequent invocations of exec_menu (after you have set it in the `choice=='1'`).

Make it global and then it will be available when you want to stop.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that's what I thought.  But my initial attempt was to declare the Global var from outside exec_menu, which did not help.  I was not sure I was on the right path before your reply.  I moved the Global inside  exec_menu and all is happy.  - thanks!